# Making Private Route in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-redux

How can I make a wrapper over my private routes, which navigate to screen only when user is authorized, otherwise redirect to login and get back to the original screen after login.
How can make this in a generalized way, so that I just reuse it on my other Private future screens?

Comment: Are you using Firebase for login?

Comment: No, Simple login from my own node server. No firebase.

Comment: Are you using `routes` map in your entry point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `routes` parameter in your `MaterialApp`, you can replace it with following implementation

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class ConditionalRouter extends MapMixin<String, WidgetBuilder> {
  final Map<String, WidgetBuilder> public;
  final Map<String, WidgetBuilder> private;

  ConditionalRouter({this.public, this.private});

  @override
  WidgetBuilder operator [](Object key) {
    if (public.containsKey(key))
      return public[key];
    if (private.containsKey(key)) {
      if (MyAuth.isUserLoggedIn)
        return private[key];
      // Adding next page parameter to your Login page
      // will allow you to go back to page, that user were going to
      return (context) => LoginPage(nextPage: key);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(key, value) {}

  @override
  void clear() {}

  @override
  Iterable<String> get keys {
    final set = Set<String>();
    set.addAll(public.keys);
    set.addAll(private.keys);
    return set;
  }

  @override
  WidgetBuilder remove(Object key) {
    return public[key] ?? private[key];
  }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
MaterialApp(
  // ...
  routes: ConditionalRouter(
    public: {
      '/start_page': (context) => StartPage()
    },
    private: {
      '/user_profile': (context) => UserProfilePage()
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for interesting solution. What are the possibilities to use the async "Auth().isAuth()" function method instead of "MyAuth.isUserLoggedIn" inside your solution? I tried a lot of variants, but no one work :( . Can you help ?

Comment: @SergeiEensalu you just have to create wrapper for `Navigator`, that's pretty straightforward to do

Comment: thank you for fast answer. I am new in Flutter, can you please give an example? :)

Comment: @SergeiEensalu that's not a one-liner comment thing ;) Post this as a separate question, maybe I will find time to answer it later

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66012904/private-and-public-routers-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Use `StreamBuilder` widget and provide it a Stream of access token/uid if there is no data then return login screen and when user is authenticated then put access token into the stream that will rebuild the StreamBuilder which return the page when user is authenticated.

Use bloc pattern or bloc library for better state management.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not using streams from my node server for authentication. Still would take a look on it.

Comment: Create a Stream in dart and when user authenticated put data in it.

Comment: I guess, he already has some static var, that says if user is logged in. Also, stream won't solve problem of routing. Also bloc could be an overkill for beginner

Answer (score 0):

Generalised idea, you could make the controller a Static variable

```
class LoginController{
  final Function onContactingServerDone;
  LoginController({this.onContactingServerDone,});

  bool loggedIn;

  login()async {
    //contact server,get token or verify token etc

    onContactingServerDone();
  }
}
```

and in your screen

```
LoginController _loginController;
initState(){
  _loginController = LoginController(onContactingServerDone: (){
    if(_loginController.loggedIn){
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('privateRoute');
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('login');
    }
  },);
  _loginController.login();
}

Widget build(context){
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```