# Navigate to next page based on a condition in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a signIn page in flutter using MongoDB, when user enters valid credentials they have to be navigated to HomePage, else they should stay in the same page. How can I achieve this logic?

when they enter valid credentials I am able to print user successful in the console, but how can I navigate to next page if it is isLogin = true?

```
 Future<String> signIn() async {
      final response = await http.post(
        serverReceiverPath,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      );
      if(response.body == 'Login successful'){
        isLogin = true;
      }else{
        isLogin = false;
      }
      print(response.body);
      print(isLogin);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Navigator`

```
  if(response.body == 'Login successful'){
    isLogin = true;
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
  }else{
    isLogin = false;
  }
```

You can learn more about it here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

You can also try my `ConditionalRouter` implementation from this recent answer: [Making Private Route in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63129318/making-private-route-in-flutter/63130011#63130011)